# What documents are available for Juju Design and Architecture?

Tags: juju, design, architecture

Where do I find Juju Design and Architecture documents?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified what you have already read or what experience level you are at. Here is a link to an [Ubuntu juju tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/users/flag-weight/18887).

Additionally, here is the link to the [chram store](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/internals/charm-store.html).
I've also found [this](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/495738-conducting-clouds-the-ubuntu-way-an-introduction-to-juju) 3rd party intro useful for a brief 3000 foot view of juju offerings.